# Character â€œ failed to convert to (") string in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I have some issues with PHP converting the characters to the correct string for my pdf.

I have tried to follow this code.

```
$title = "â€œTUK SI KECILâ€ Baby Food Provider";
$title = mb_convert_encoding($title, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
echo $title; // &ldquo;TUK SI KECIL&rdquo; Baby Food Provider
```

What I want:

> "TUK SI KECIL" Baby Food Provider

Please help.

Comment: echo  html_entity_decode($title);

Comment: Why do you think `â€œ` should be a left double-quote? Are you working with corrupt data? Or have you echo’d or inspected something and that’s just what you saw?

Comment: You get ```&ldquo;``` and  ```&rdquo;``` pair `“` (U+201C,  *Left Double Quotation Mark*) and `”` (U+201D,  *Right Double Quotation Mark*) instead of  a pair of  `"` (U+0022,  *Quotation Mark*)s. BTW, where the `$title` string comes from? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ChrisHaas it's a  [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (`â€œ` -> ```&ldquo;```) as follows: `var_dump( mb_convert_encoding( mb_convert_encoding("â€œ", 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8'), 'HTML-ENTITIES'));` returns `string(7) "&ldquo;"`… Unfortunately, I can't do analogical conversion for ```&rdquo;```  from `â€\x9D` string literal (nor from the `â€\u{9D}` one).

Comment: mojibake is just a form of data corruption. What I'm trying to figure out is if you are trying to fix existing data, or just account for it and leave part of the process broken.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I agree.  That's why I ask the OP *where the `$title` string comes from?*

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ, I missed the name and thought your comment was actually the OP's response